# Using Gmail Alias to Send HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail

I am using the following code to send a Google sheet-derived HTML table and some text via gmail. I can successfully send it from my 'default' subscriber account, but not from a functioning alias account.

I want to send it from that alias.

I know to implement GmailApp.getAliases();, I know what number the alias I want to use is, I just cannot get the HTML output into the email.

The closest I have come is just "object."

Any advice, suggested code, very welcome. Thank you!

```
 function getEmailHtml(appearanceData){
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template.html");
  htmlTemplate.appearance = appearanceData;
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  return htmlBody;}

function sendEmail() {
  var appearanceData = getData();
  var body = getEmailText(appearanceData);
  var htmlBody = getEmailHtml(appearanceData);


MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "xxx@xxxx.com",
    cc: "xxx@xxxx.com",
    subject: "XXX XXX XXX",
    body: body,
    htmlBody: htmlBody
      });

  function getEmailText(appearanceData) {
  var text = "";
  appearanceData.forEach(function(appearance) {
  text = text + appearance.client + "\n" + appearance.court + "\n" + appearance.date + "\n" + appearance.time + "\n" + appearance.charges + "\n" + appearance.notes +"\n" + appearance.phone +"\n-----------------------\n\n";
  });
  return text;
}

/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function getData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var startRow = 2;  
  var startCol = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;  
  var numCols = 10; 


  sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols);

  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols).getDisplayValues();
  values.shift(); //remove headers
  var appearances = [];
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    var appearance = {};
    appearance.client = value[0];
    appearance.court = value[1];
    appearance.date = value[2];
    appearance.time = value[3];
    appearance.charges = value[4];
    appearance.notes = value[5];
    appearance.phone = value[6];
    appearances.push(appearance);

     
  
})
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(appearances));
  return appearances;
```

}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [GmailApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) instead of the [MailApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)?

I think you can use something like this:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, 'This is the subject of the email', 
                                 'Please see the body of the email.', {
    to: "xxx@xxxx.com",
    cc: "xxx@xxxx.com",
    subject: "XXX XXX XXX",
    body: body,
    from: aliases[0]
    name: "Sender Name", 
    htmlBody: htmlBody
      });
```

I took as base the samples on the Google Documentation for [getAliases()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getaliases) and [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options).

The issue was fixed with this change:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(
      "XXX@XX.com",
      "Outlook",
       body,{
            cc: "xxx@xxxx.com",
            from: "xxx@xxxx.com",
            htmlBody: htmlBody,
          }
        );
```

Comment: I have implemented the following code (similar to yours) in another script that sends from a sheet and works, but the html is iterated within the script. I think the issue lies in the use of an html template and possibly the getEmailText function:

     var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {from: alias[0], htmlBody: html, 
   cc:'XXX@XXX.com'});

Comment: ^ that's the script that calls the alias and works, with the html iterated within the script.

Comment: From what I see in your code, you are using an HTML template with Scriptlets like <?= client ?> to add the information, I personally usually add call the HTML template and the GmailApp.sendEmail as part of the loop forEach, so it sends the email as part of each iteration.

Comment: I also add the Alias as a global variable instead of adding it with the iteration from: aliases[0] since it can create issues with the iteration in the loop filling out the information for the Scriptlets.

Comment: Thanks Giselle - can you send me a sample of code where you employ forEach in this context so I can see it?

Comment: I will search for it since it was an old project. I usually use a simple now like this `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){ }`

Comment: I'm edited the answer with more information.

Comment: Oh cool. Let me see what that does.

Comment: So I am not using this to send out a large number of emails, it's one email sent once a week, all the non duplicate stuff isn't necessary. When I add your code and try to run it I get this error: 

Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
eval 
eval 
getEmailHtml @ Code.gs:6

Line 6 is var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

So for some reason it is not parsing htmlBody.

Frustrating. Just want to send from an alias!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246683/discussion-between-giselle-valladares-and-jon-win).

Comment: I'm editing once more the answer with the code that fixed the issue.

Comment: @jon_win
If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)